# Generating Excel file with Pre-poulated Dropdown Values with C#'s Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I want to generate an `Excel` file from my `C#` application, which users will be able to fill in later on. I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

I'm launching `Excel` and populating the header cells using the below code:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application {Visible = true};
var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
var workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) workbook.Worksheets.Item[1];

headers.Select((s, i) => new Tuple<string, int>(s, i)).ToList().ForEach
    (
     h => { workSheet.Cells[1, h.Item2 + 1] = h.Item1; }
    );
```

**How can I specify that the first column's cells should have a drop-down containing pre-populated values?**

I've tried loads of things available online, such as the below found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27720154/how-to-populate-a-dropdown-in-excel-from-c.html), without luck:

```
var dropDownRange = workSheet.Range["A2"].Resize[64000];
dropDownRange.Value = Values;
dropDownRange = dropDownRange.Offset[0, 1];
dropDownRange.Validation.Delete();
dropDownRange.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, Type.Missing, "=DropDownList");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula parameter expects a comma separated string of values when applying a validation limiting to a list. Here is an example that creates a dropdown with three values:

```
var items = new List<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
var formattedItems = string.Join(", ", items.ToArray());

var dropDownRange = workSheet.Range["A2"].EntireColumn;
dropDownRange.Validation.Delete();
dropDownRange.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
    Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
    Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
    formattedItems,
    Type.Missing);
```

Also if you need to default the cells to a value you can do this:

```
dropDownRange.Value = "Item 2";
```

or even better:

```
dropDownRange.Value = items[1];
```